# How to change HTML table td width?

Tags: jquery, html

Here's my current code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stripeMe tr").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("over");
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    });
    $(".stripeMe tr:even").addClass("alt");
});


<table class="stripeMe" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:85%">Product Name</td>
        <td style="width:5%; text-align:right">Price (each)</td>
        <td style="width:5%; text-align:center">Quantity</td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
    </tr>

    <% foreach (var cart in Model.Carts) { %>
        <tr id="row-<%: cart.RecordID %>">
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink(Model.pr.GetProduct(cart.ProductID).ProductName.Length > 52 ? (string)Model.pr.GetProduct(cart.ProductID).ProductName.Substring(0, 52) + "..." :  (string)Model.pr.GetProduct(cart.ProductID).ProductName, "Elaborate", "Product", new { ProductID = cart.ProductID, RecordID = cart.RecordID }, null)%>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
                <%: (string)String.Format("{0:F}",Model.pr.GetProduct(cart.ProductID).UnitPrice) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" style="text-align:center; border-width:0; background-color:transparent" id="column-Quantity-<%: cart.RecordID %>" value="<%: cart.Quantity %>"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Remove from Cart", "RemoveFromCart", new { RecordID = cart.RecordID }, new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess = "handleUpdate" })%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>

    <tr>
        <td><hr />Total</td>
        <td align="right">
            <hr />
            <span id="cart-total"><%: (string)String.Format("{0:F}",Model.CartTotal) %></span>
         </td>
         <td align="center">
             <hr />
             <span id="cart-quantity"><%: Model.CartQuantity %></span>
         </td>
         <td><hr />&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

No matter how I change it, it doesn't work. I'm using the latest version of Firefox.

```
<td style="width:85%">Product Name</td>
```

Comment: How exactly does this not work? Is that `td` the same width as the others?

Comment: there are four td, their width are 85% 5% 5% 5%. but when i change them to 70% 20% 5% 5% or 60% 10% 20% 10%, after the screen refresh, it looks nothing change. still keep same with looking as 85% 5% 5% 5%

Comment: I tried the changes in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HZTpf/) and they seem to work alright. There is nothing wrong with your HTML. Plus you DO have a `text-align:right` in your 2nd `td` which might make the change even less apparent.

Comment: but my code still not working ???

Comment: Then there is something else going on in your site. Something that doesn't appear in the code posted.

Comment: Even I remove all td width, it still keep the same appearing.

Comment: Thanks "rae 1n" the issue fixed, see my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like say "THANK YOU" to everybody who put effort to help me out, especially thanks to "rae1n", "Deminoth Bono", "tristan" and "OMG" !!! all you guys effort help me figure out the issue and solve it.

First I use firefox "error console", I find a javascript issue which is sit there long time, then I fix it, but unfortunately our "Width" issue still there.

Second from "rae1n" and "OMG" post, I start to thought this may not an " width" issue, so I start to look around, after one day thinking......, finally I figure out the issue is at input type="text" tag. You know, if you do not give a width in the input type="text", it will render an textbox with fix width looks like 200px, this cause the issue. So what ever how I change the "td" percentage, it still keep same looking. So I add style="width:100%" into the input type="text"...  , then change the "td" width, the "td" width show correct changing. the issue get fixed. Below code is how I correct it.

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" style="width:100%; text-align:center; border-width:0; background-color:transparent" id="column-Quantity-<%: cart.RecordID %>" value="<%: cart.Quantity %>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `table-layout:fixed` style to the table, as such,

`<table class="stripeMe" width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed">`

to make the change more apparent.

However, using this setting will overflow the content into adjacent `td`.

Comment: @Matthew Can I see your webpage?

Comment: This web site has not been publish yet.

Comment: table-layout:fixed will make the table's width depends on itself and  columns' width, border, margin, spacing only rather than the contents inside. The width of td depends on its width only, such as 85% here; So I agree with Bono's answer. @Mathew, could you do a screenshot to clearify the page result?

Comment: Thanks "Deminoth", the issue fixed see my post below.

Comment: Thanks "tristan", the issue fixed see my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/DEU7d/1/

The class .alt is getting added to 'even' rows on page load. (i added a color for .alt)

The class .over is getting toggled between mouse over and out .

CSS

```
.over { background:#88aa4d; }
.alt { color: #ff881a; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".stripeMe tr").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("over");
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("over");
});

$(".stripeMe tr:even").addClass("alt");
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="stripeMe" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:85%">Product Name</td>
        <td style="width:5%; text-align:right">Price (each)</td>
        <td style="width:5%; text-align:center">Quantity</td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
    </tr>
        <tr id="row-1">
            <td>
                linktext1
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
               price
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" style="text-align:center; border-width:0; background-color:transparent" id="column-Quantity-1" value="12"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                iink text2
            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="even" id="row-2">
            <td>
                linktext1
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
               price
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" disabled="disabled" style="text-align:center; border-width:0; background-color:transparent" id="column-Quantity-2" value="21"></input>
            </td>
            <td>
                iink text2
            </td>
        </tr>


    <tr>
        <td><hr />Total</td>
        <td align="right">
            <hr />
            <span id="cart-total">total</span>
         </td>
         <td align="center">
             <hr />
             <span id="cart-quantity">quantity</span>
         </td>
         <td><hr />&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: @Matthew, the above jsfiddle proves that the jquery fuctions are working properly. If it is not working still in your side then try firebug cosole to find javascript errors. also make sure the style sheet was loaded. pls let me know.

Comment: Thanks "OMG", the issue fixed, see my post below.